# google plus is not reading meta tag from page

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

As I am using angularjs, it is not possible to write meta tags in each page. So,I created separate page with meta tags for sharing purpose.

```
    <html>

    <head>
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
        <meta property="og:image" content="">
        <meta property="og:description" content="description">
</head>

    <body>
        <h1>page</h1>
         </body>

    </html>
```

But google plus is not reading meta tags from this page and coming blank in share window.
Please somebody help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Well, not sure what you mean by "not possible to write meta tags in each page", but the first issue that I see is that you are trying to put meta tags on the body instead of in the head... Check out this [link](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: Tried placing meta tags inside header tag but no luck.